# Friend function not declared in this scope error

Tags: c++, declaration, friend-function

Hi I am trying to understand the scope of friend functions and I get a "not declared in scope" error. Here is my code:

```
//node.h
class Node{

public:

  int id;
  int a;
  int b;

  friend int add(int,int);

  void itsMyLife(int);
  Node();
};

//node.cpp
Node::Node(){
  a=0;
  b=0;
  id=1;
}

void Node::itsMyLife(int x){

  cout<<"In object "<<id<<" add gives "<<add(x,a)<<endl;

}

//routing.cpp
#include "node.h"

int add(int x, int y){

     return x+y;
}

//main.cpp
#include "node.h"

int main(){

return 0;
}
```

I get the error "add not declared in this scope" in node.cpp. Why do I get this error when I have declared the function in the class scope? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK friend declaration is also a forward declaration. If I'm right there shouldn't be an error. Maybe it sees it as in the class scope (though that doesn't make much sense for a friend function), try adding :: before add in the friend declaration to declare it is in the global scope and not class scope. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Actually the problem disappears if I define the add function in node.cpp. But I want to define it in a separate file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Inside your node class you declare a friend function int add (int, int). However, currently the compiler hasn't encountered the function yet and therefore it is unknown.

You could make a separate header and source file for your add function. Then in node.h include you new header. Because in the file where you declare Node the function add is not known currently.

So you might make a add.h and a add.cpp file for example and include add.h before declaring Node. Don't forget to compile add.cpp as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response but that is not the objective of my question. I want to know why a member function cannot call a friend function when the friend function has already been declared in the class? Actually I want to call the friend function in a member function and the friend function has to access some private member variables of the class (not shown in code for simplicity). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its a bug on the the Linux side. The code should work. I have code right now that compiles fine on the Windows side and when I move it to the Linux side I get the same error. Apparently the compiler that you are using on the Linux side does not see/use the friend declaration in the header file and hence gives this error.
By simply moving the of the friend function's implementation in the C++ file BEFORE that function's usage (e.g.: as might be used in function callback assignment), this resolved my issue and should resolve yours also.

Best Regards

Comment: Previous comment should have read: It is a bug on the the Linux side. The code should work as written. I have code right now that compiles fine on the Windows side and when I move it to the Linux side I get the same error. Apparently the compiler that you are using on the Linux side does not see/use the friend declaration in the header file and hence gives this error.
By simply moving the friend function's definition/implementation in the C++ file *BEFORE* that function's usage (e.g.: as might be used in function callback assignment), this resolved my issue and should resolve yours also.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Please explain precisely what you mean by moving the friend function's definition in the C++ file before the function's usage. I don't understand what that means. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually declared the function.

```
extern int add(int, int);
```

Comment: In which file do I put this declaration?

Comment: thanks! Got that! Actually the problem disappears if I define the add function in node.cpp. But I wanted to define it in a separate file. Why do we have to declare it separately with extern in the header file?

Comment: The compiler has to know what fingerprints of a function exist before it can produce code to call it correctly (you could have variants of 'add' with different argument types: long, float, double, char, etc) or perhaps default values.

So you need a prototype declaration for the function before you first call it, and the "friend" definition doesn't count as a prototype declaration (it would be a weird context in which to declare a non-member function from).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "node.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node{
public:
    int id;
    int a;
    int b;

    friend int add(Node &a);
    void itsMyLife(int);
    Node();
};

//node.cpp
Node::Node(){
    a=0;
    b=0;
    id=1;
}

void Node::itsMyLife(int x):b(x){
    cout<<"In object "<<id<<" add gives "<<add(Node &a)<<endl;
}

//routing.cpp
#include "node.h"

int add(Node &a){
    return a.b+a.y;
}

//main.cpp

int main(){
    Node n;
    n.ItsMyLife(15);
    cout<<add(n);
    return 0;
}
```

This should work fine - I guess. The syntax for "friend" function is -- friend {returntype} {functionname} (class_name &object_name). To access any of the members of the class use object_name.variable_name.