# Error: 'Friend Member Function Name' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux, oop, codeblocks, friend

I am in the process of moving all of my C++ Windows applications to Ubuntu Linux. This application runs fine on Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 7 OS. However, it gives an error when running in Code Blocks on Ubuntu Linux. I have replicated the error message I am getting using the following simple `Person` class.

> Error Message: 'comparePersonAge' was not declared in this scope

#### Person.h

```
#ifndef Person_h
#define Person_h

#include <string>

class Person
{
private:
    int age;
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(int a, std::string n) : age(a), name(n) {}

    int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    std::string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    inline friend bool comparePersonAge(const Person& p1, const Person& p2)
    {
        return p1.age < p2.age;
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "Person.h"

int main()
{
    Person p1(93, "harold");
    Person p2(32, "james");
    Person p3(67, "tracey");

    std::vector<Person> v;
    v.push_back(p1);
    v.push_back(p2);
    v.push_back(p3);

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparePersonAge);

    std::cout << v[0].getAge() << " " << v[1].getAge() << " " << v[2].getAge()  << std::endl;
}
```

On Windows machine, the output is: `32 67 93` as expected. On Linux, the error message is as written above.

**Note:** Someone else name DJR discusses this issue in this post: [Friend function not declared in this scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780013/friend-function-not-declared-in-this-scope-error).
However, his explanation is very vague I and don't follow his steps.

He writes:

> Previous comment should have read: It is a bug on the the Linux side. The code should work as written. I have code right now that compiles fine on the Windows side and when I move it to the Linux side I get the same error. Apparently the compiler that you are using on the Linux side does not see/use the friend declaration in the header file and hence gives this error. By simply moving the friend function's definition/implementation in the C++ file BEFORE that function's usage (e.g.: as might be used in function callback assignment), this resolved my issue and should resolve yours also.

I don't know what he means by by moving the friend function's definition in the C++ file before the function's usage. What does this mean precisely?

Comment: That syntax is available with the current standard only AFAIK. Are you sure `--std=c++11` is used when compiling your code?

Comment: Remove the 'inline' on `comparePersonAge` and try it again on Linux. I'm thinking that because you're passing the function to `std::sort` it needs to be an actual function, not just be inlined, and apparently the compiler you're using on Linux isn't bright enough to handle this.

Comment: @BobJarvis Removing 'inline' does not solve the problem. I am using Code Blocks with C++11 compiler.

Comment: Also, to be passed to `std::sort` doesn't `comparePersonAge` need to be `static`?

Comment: @BobJarvis It's a friend, not a member.

Comment: @molbdnilo - whoops. Overlooked that...

Comment: Using `comparePersonAge` "standalone" (not passing it to `std::sort`) works as it should. I suspect that it's a g++ bug.

Comment: @BobJarvis Changing comparePersonAge to static will induce an additional error on CodeBlocks in Linux: 'Storage class specifiers invalid in friend function declarations'. On the other side, the application will run fine in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows.

Comment: @molbdnilo How does one get around these g++ bugs? How can I modify the above code to do the same work, while not inducing the compilation error?

Comment: @ChristineSimmons Write the function's definition outside the class, leaving only a friend declaration inside it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ which syntax?

Comment: @AngelusMortis The inlined `friend` function.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the `friend` keyword is to make an exception to the access rules (`protected` and `private`), giving a class or function access to members not otherwise allowed.

So you can declare and define your `comparePersonAge()` function outside of your class declaration, and use the `friend` keyword inside the declaration, to give the function access to private members, `age` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Standard 7.3.1.2/3 :

> Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that
>   namespace. **If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares
>   a class or function the friend class or function is a member of the
>   innermost enclosing namespace. The name of the friend is not found by
>   unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or by qualified lookup (3.4.3) until a
>   matching declaration is provided in that namespace scope (either
>   before or after the class definition granting friendship). If a friend
>   function is called, its name may be found by the name lookup that
>   considers functions from namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the function arguments (3.4.2)** . If the name in a friend
>   declaration is neither qualified nor a template-id and the declaration
>   is a function or an elaborated-type-specifier, the lookup to determine
>   whether the entity has been previously declared shall not consider any
>   scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace.

Ok after little discussion with @Niall I realized that MSVC++ is wrong in this case, since ADL only happens in function call expression and since `std::sort` is being passed just name of function i.e `comparePersonAge`, no function `comparePersonAge` should be found at the time of call to `std::sort` . Hence GCC and Clang are correct I think

Comment: So gcc (and clang) are correct? `comparePersonAge` has no arguments in as provided to `sort`.

Comment: @Niall Sorry but I'm not sure what you're saying

Comment: Ok, I think they are correct to reject the code. When `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comparePersonAge);` is complied, `comparePersonAge` has no arguments, so there is no ADL and since there is no matching declaration in the namespace scope, it can't be found.

Comment: I 'm sorry but I just realized that too, since ADL only happens in function call but since `std::sort` is being passed just name of function, no function `comparePersonAge` should be found

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

1. There's no need to specify `inline` if it's defined within the class.
2. Although that declaration yields a [friend function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Notes) which is a member of the enclosing namespace of the class, until it's declared *in that namespace* explicitly, it's not available for regular lookup—though ADL is allowed.

So if you want to make it accessible via regular lookup, declare it in the enclosing namespace.

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/DWC97124)</kbd>